# How to match label values with chart line in react native and d3?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, d3.js

Hey guys I try to create my first chart using react native and d3 but two issues I found here. First is that while I am playing with cursor position in label is not equal with label. And second issue is that I want to match the graph with months behind scrolling both.

here I made a snack example

https://snack.expo.io/@zoolle/chart-with-d3

Any idea?

Comment: I had a play with it, and changed `const scaleLabel = scaleLinear().domain([0, 1200]).range([0, 1200]);` to use a linear scale and this gave a result for the [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vIKc.png) that made more sense.  Rather than it jumping to `-100`  at random points.

Comment: What I try to do is a graphic of earnings for months. So in a specific month you've earned $900 in next month you have overdrawn of a 100 so your value is $-100. I need this to be drawn by d3 and also to be specified in label

Comment: Ok I understand. So your graph is wrong as well.